# Definition of $*$-endomorphisms on a $C^*$-algebra

Tags: reference-request, definition, c-star-algebras

I'm reading a paper which talks about $*$-endomorphisms on a $C^*$-algebra without defining the notion. I browsed through various books on $C^*$-algebras but could not find a definition. I only found a definition of an endomorphism on a measure space $(\Omega,\mu)$.

> What is the standard definition of a $*$-endomorphism on a $C^*$-algebra?

Comment: A $*$-morphism between two c* algebras $A, B$ is a map $A\to B$ that is (i) linear, (ii) multiplicative, (iii) respects the involution. In other words if $\varphi$ is a $*$-morphism you have (i) $\varphi(\lambda a+ b)=\lambda\varphi(a)+\varphi(b)$, (ii) $\varphi(ab)=\varphi(a)\varphi(b)$ (iii) $\varphi(a^*)=\varphi(a)^*$ for all $a,b\in A$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb K$. An endomorphism is then a $*$-morphism where the domain and codomain agree (ie a morphism from $A$ to $A$).

Comment: Note that the norms of $A$ and $B$ are not mentioned in this definition, but it is a fact that any $*$-morphism between c* algebras is automatically continuous, infact any such $*$-morphism is necessarily a _contraction_.

Comment: @s.harp Oh so just a $*$-homomorphism between the same space?

Comment: Yes, endomorphism generally means "morphism with domain and codomain being equal", same as isomorphism means "morphism admitting an inverse" and epimorphism means etc ...  see eg here for more names:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphism#Some_special_morphisms

Comment: @s.harp I get it now. If you turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word endomorphism is used to denote a morphism where both the domain and the codomain coincide, meaning a morphism $\varphi : A\to B$ is an endomorphism iff $A=B$. According to wiktionary the root of the "endo-" is the greek $\mathrm{\epsilon\nu\delta\omicron\nu}$, meaning "inner".

For C* algebras the appropriate notion of morphism is that of a $*$-morphism, so here an endomorphism of a C*algebra $A$ is a map $\varphi:A\to A$ satisfying

1. Linearity: $\varphi(\lambda a+ b) = \lambda\varphi(a)+\varphi(b)$ for all $a,b\in A$, $\lambda\in \Bbb K$.
2. Multiplicativity $\varphi(ab)= \varphi(a)\varphi(b)$ for all $a,b\in A$.
3. Compatibility with $*$: $\varphi(a^*)=\varphi(a)^*$ for all $a\in A$.